# Euler equation for $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-rt}(x^2+2x+\dot x^2) \ \mathrm dt$? Is $\infty$ in the boundary open or closed?

Tags: control-theory, operations-research

I am pondering this problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv7bJ.png), the course [Mat-2.3148 Dynamic Optimization](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3148) in Aalto University, i.e.

> Find the function $x(t)$ such that $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-rt}(x^2+2x+\dot x^2)\ \mathrm dt$ has the largest value when $x(0)=1$.

I believed that the Euler is $g_x-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}g_{\dot x} =0$ but I cannot get the solution $1+x+rx'-x''=0$. I believe we use non-extended $\mathbb R$ (not containing $\infty$ as point) so I believe I have here a closed $t_i$ and open $t_f$?

What is the Euler equation with the closed boundary $t_i=0$ and $t_f$ to $\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over complicating it.  The solution you provided assumes $t_f<\infty$, but then takes a limit, so the Euler-Lagrange equation does not change.  To work out the Euler-Lagrange differential equation:

Start with the argument of the integral 
$$
L=e^{-rt}\left(x^2+2x+\dot{x}^2\right)
$$

Then the time derivative of the partial of the Lagrangian, $L$, with respect to $\dot{x}$ is
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}=2e^{-rt}\dot{x}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left\{\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right\}=-2re^{-rt}\dot{x}+2e^{-rt}\ddot{x}.
$$

Looking at the derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to $x$ we get
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=2e^{-rt}x+2e^{-rt}.
$$

Finally, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt}\left\{\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right\}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=&-2re^{-rt}\dot{x}+2e^{-rt}\ddot{x}-(2e^{-rt}x+2e^{-rt})&=0\\
=&\ddot{x}-r\dot{x}-x-1&=0.
\end{eqnarray*}

From here we solve this to get 
$$
x(t)=-1+C_1e^{\lambda_+t}+C_2e^{\lambda_-t}
$$
where 
$$
\lambda_\pm=\frac{r\pm\sqrt{r^2+4}}{2}.
$$
Now, plug x(0)=1 into the equation and you get the expression that $C_2=2-C_1$. Finally, notice that in order for the integral to be finite you must cancel out the term with the positive eigenvalue ($\lambda_+$) so $C_1=2$, i.e. the solution.

Comment: So is the boundary closed or open in $\mathbb R$? I think $t_f$ is closed because no neighborhood coming from $\infty$. And $t_i$ is open because of the neighbourhood coming from negative side. So the $[t_i,t_f[$ is clopen (Its complement $]-\infty,0_-[$ is open set). Hmmm...I need to understand it better what closed boundary and open boundary means?

Comment: They are just definitions. @riboch could do this better. There is something unclear to me too in his proposal.